# Ensuring one AngularJS controller loads before another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll preface this with the fact that I really have no idea if this is the best way to achieve what I'm doing and I'm very open to better suggestions.

I've got a user account system using `OAUTH2` which gets looks up user info in my database and saves it as a variable, `$rootScope.userInfo`. This resides in a controller which is appended to my app's `body`; here I was thinking that the highest-level controller would load before those that live within it, but apparently not.

If I load a view which tries to access this `$rootScope.userInfo` object before my `mainCtrl` has had a chance to load it in from my database, it throws a javascript error and `Angular` breaks.

For reference, here's a rough idea of the template:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <header>Content</header>
    <div class='main-view' ng-controller="userProfile">
        <p>{{user.name}}</p>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm loading `$rootScope.userInfo` in `mainCtrl` like this:

```
$http.get('/api/users/' + $cookies.id).
    success(function(data) {
      $rootScope.userInfo = data.user[0];
      console.log("User info is:");
      console.log($rootScope.userInfo);
      $scope.status = 'ready';
    });
```

Then for my `userProfile` control, I do:

```
function userProfile($scope, $cookies, $http, $routeParams, $rootScope){
  if($scope.status == 'ready'){
    $scope.user = $rootScope.userInfo;
    console.log("Double checking user info, here it is:");
    console.log($rootScope.userInfo);
  }
}
```

If I'm coming from a different page in the app which doesn't call on `$rootScope.userInfo`, the API has enough time to look it up and my `userProfile` page works fine. However if doing a full-page refresh, the `$rootScope.userInfo` doesn't have time to load and I get errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem you describe is one of the reasons why it is not recommended to share data between controllers using `$rootScope`: it creates a manual "invisible" dependency between two controllers, that you have to manually fix when the end user hasn't gone through the other controller yet.

The recommended solution is to move the user loading logic into a service, say `userProfileService`, which you inject into both controllers that need it. It will then be created once, and used for both controllers. In such a service you could load the user profile  with `$http` when a controller asks for it, and return it from cache when the next one does. This way, the dependency goes from both controllers to a shared service, rather than from one controller to another.

I'm not a huge fan of the AngularJS documentation, but these might help: [DI](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), [Creating Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), and [Injecting Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.injecting_controllers).

Comment: This is pretty close, I like the idea of using it as a service. However it doesn't solve the loading-order issue. I have the service set up, but it still loads the controller before the service has returned any data! ideas?

Comment: I've made an updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477711/force-angularjs-service-to-return-data-before-loading-controller I'll accept this as the answer as it does most of the job, but feel free to answer that one too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `then` instead of success and delay the loading of the child controller using `ng-include`:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <header>Content</header>
    <ng-include src="templatePath"></ng-include>        
</body>
```

Move the HTML inside a new template `userprofile.html`:

```
<div class='main-view' ng-controller="userProfile">
    <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    <p>{{user.email}}</p>
</div>
```

Callback inside the mainCtrl:

```
$http.get('/api/users/' + $cookies.id).
    then(function(data) {
        /* mainCtrl being the parent controller, simply exposing the 
           properties to $scope would make them available 
           to all the child controllers.*/
        $rootScope.userInfo = data.user[0];
        /* assign the template path to load the template and 
           instantiate the controller */
        $scope.templatePath = "userprofile.html";
    });
```

Comment: `$http.success(foo)` is an alias of `$http.then(foo)` that passes all of the arguments correctly. What would changing `success` to `then` solve? See [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L673).

Comment: @stevuu Yep. It seems there's no point in using one over the other.