# Force AngularJS service to return data before loading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service in Angular which uses my API to get user information and provides it to my controllers. It's set up like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ngResource', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'seo'])
  .service('userInfo', function($http, $cookies){
    $http.get('/api/users/' + $cookies.id).
    success(function(data) {
      var userInfo = data.user[0];

      return userInfo;
    });
  }). // other stuff comes after this
```

In my controllers, I include it like:

```
function userProfile($scope, $cookies, userInfo, $http, $resource, $routeParams, $rootScope){
    $scope.user = userInfo;
    console.log('user info is')
    console.log(userInfo);
```

This is returning no data, while if I put the same service function in the controller itself it returns just fine. What am I missing here? Never used DI/Services in Angular before so might be a simple mistake somewhere.

I need to ensure that the service returns data ***before*** the controller loads. How can this be accomplished

Comment: you could simplify your console.logs like this:
`console.log('user info is ', userInfo);`

Comment: @EddieMongeJr really? had no idea, thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can make the factory to return a promise like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'ngResource', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'seo'])
    .service('userInfo', function ($http, $cookies) {
    var promise = $http.get('/api/users/' + $cookies.id).
    success(function (data) {
        var userInfo = data.user[0];
        return userInfo;
    });
    return promise;
}) // other stuff comes after this
```

And in your controller, do

```
function userProfile($scope, $cookies, userInfo, $http, $resource, $routeParams, $rootScope){
    userInfo.then(function(data){
        $scope.user = data;
    });
}
```

This can guarantee that whenever you use the service, it always gives you the data *synchronously*, you don't have to necessarily load any data before loading the controller.

Comment: Promises can be assigned directly to the `$scope`. When the promise resolves, Angular automatically updates the view.

Comment: Note that promises are not automatically unwrapped in angular 1.2+.

Comment: is this really working? i see promise injected not the actual data from response

Answer (score 17):

Your `userInfo` service has to return the promise returned by `$http`. That promise will then be injected into your controller, and the view will be updated as soon as the promise successfully resolves.

---

If you don't want the view to be rendered at all before `userInfo` resolves, you should set a `resolve` property on your route, and inject your service there:

```
$routeProvider.when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile',
    controller: userProfile,
    resolve: {
         userInfoData: function ($q, userInfo) {
             return userInfo;
         }
    }
});
```

Then just inject `userInfoData` into your controller in place of the `userInfo` service.

Comment: I need this data available to all controllers/routes, is there a particular way to inject it once so I don't have to do it 20+ times for each route?

Comment: @Jascination - Not that I know of. I think you'll just have to set that `resolve: resolveUserInfo` for all the routes that you need it for.

Comment: Interesting. I've tried your solution but it's still doing the same thing - loading controller before data resolves. I know this probably shouldn't be the case due to `resolve`, I'm assuming it's an async/callback issue as the `resolveUserInfo` function isn't finishing loading data before returning.

Comment: @Jascination - Have you returned the `$http` promise from the service?

Comment: Any chance of accomplishing this without using routes? http://stackoverflow.com/q/29889040/4341650

Comment: This is a nice tip. Helped me get a smooth transition between pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the resource object to your variable like that
return $http.get(url)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem in which I had to load data into a service using $resource and get that data into controllers $scope.
I didn't wanted to directly return the promise and then use a resolver in the controller (as @zsong wrote) but to do all the magic into the service once and use the ability to assign a promise directly to a $scope as @Joseph Silber point out, so here is what I did :

```
return function($scope){promise.then(function(data){$scope.user = data})};
```

And used it in the controller like this :

```
userInfo($scope);
```

Not much of an improvement but it allowed me  a clearer syntax in my controllers, hope it'll help even three years later !