# $http request is not returning response from a service in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

In my MEAN Stack application when I want to return a static response from a service, I can get the result on controller, and when I want my response with a $http request its not returning the valid data.

Here is my ***service page***-

```
'use strict';
angular.module('products').factory('ProductSharedService', function($rootScope, $http) {
    var sharedService = {
        getProductList: function (theScope) {
            // Working 
            theScope.productList = {'testkey':'testvalue', 'demokey':'demovalue'};

            // Not working           
            $http.get('/products').then(function(response) {
                theScope.productList = response;
            });
        }
    };

    return sharedService;
});
```

And here is the ***controller page***  -

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('InviteController', ['$scope', 'ProductSharedService', '$stateParams', 'Authentication', '$http',
function($scope, ProductSharedService, $stateParams, Authentication, $http) {

$scope.getMembers = function() {
    $scope.productList = {};
    ProductSharedService.getProductList($scope);    //  Get all product from "ProductSharedService" service

    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.productList));
    console.log($scope.productList);
};
```

Here is the **result with *static data***. You can see the returned object.
[image]

And the **result with *$http request***. Now there is nothing.
[image]

The $http request will give me the following, if I place it on controller -

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5537cdef3c3a11cd3baa90f8"), "artist" : "test artistname", "title" : "test title", "dimensions" : "140x145", "medium" : "test medium", "price" : 140, "provenance" : "test"}
```

I have looked at the other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755201/angularjs-http-get-to-get-json-not-working-in-the-service-layer) related to mine, but those did not help me with the current problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you are claiming that the route /products does not work, but you are looking at the results of a request made to /modules

Comment: maybe the $http call is working after i got my response..

Comment: @Bimper, this question is related to MEAN js, maybe I need help with the $q (promise) or $on or $broadcast ... but I did not find any helpful answer which solved my case.

Comment: No you need to log your data within promise callback but since you never return anything from service you should consider rewriting service. Passing scope as argument is backwards... try passing a callback instead, or most would return the `$http` promise. Study some tutorials

Comment: @charlietfl, Thanks, as your suggestion I added promise and it is working now..

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question just to help others to know which I did or suggested to do.

***Service file changes  -***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('products').service('ProductSharedService', function($http) {
    this.getProductList = function(){
        return $http.get('/products');
    };
});
```

***Controller file changes -***

```
angular.module('core').controller('InviteController', ['$scope', 'ProductSharedService', '$stateParams', 'Authentication', '$http',
    function($scope, ProductSharedService, $stateParams, Authentication, $http) {
        $scope.getMembers = function() {
            var promise = ProductSharedService.getProductList();
            promise.then(function(data) {
                $scope.productList = data;
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.productList));
                console.log($scope.productList);
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

I found the above changes helped me in my case.

Comment: You don't need `$q` for this ....  `$http` already returns a promise, just return `$http` from service