# Why does AngularJS "$http.get().then(...)" work on plain text files, but not JSON files?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-promise

Here are two demos of using AngularJS "$http.get().then(...)". One reads plain text files, and the other reads JSON files.

[read plain text](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdMEKh?p=preview) vs [read JSON](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBUihTWffeqbVZXFGvj2?p=preview)

However, the first one works but the second doesn't. Everything else is the same, except for file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, and line 23 of app.js.

```
  /* content of file: 100 */

  function getNumber(file) {
      return $http.get(file).then(function(response){
         return parseInt(response.data, 10);
      });
  }
```

vs

```
  /* content of file: [{'n':100}] */

  function getNumber(file) {
      return $http.get(file).then(function(response){
         return response[0].n;
      });
  }
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755201/angularjs-http-get-to-get-json-not-working-in-the-service-layer) post by trying to create a service but still got some errors.

Basically, how to make the second one work? Thanks in advance! It would be more explicit if you look at the demos.

Comment: Perhaps `response.data[0].n` ?

Comment: No. that's not the problem. You can try it. @PSL

Comment: Which errors are you receiving from the 2nd?

Comment: Note that the file contents aren't quite valid [JSON](http://json.org/). Strings, including object keys, have to be delimited by double-quotes -- `content of file: [{"n":100}]`

Comment: aah you got invalid JSON there. you must use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLonowski! such a silly mistake. Thanks @PSL as well.

Comment: and use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() for manipulate JSON/TEXT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[{'n':100}]` is not valid JSON. Change it to `[{"n":100}]`