# Angular resolve not working as expected on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want my Angular application to resolve a promise before changing the route to a certain path:

```
va.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/sendungen', {templateUrl: '../partials/sendungen.php',   controller: 'OverviewCtrl',resolve: {
            shipments: oc.fetchAllShipments
        }}).
        // ...
}]);
```

The funcion fetchAllShipments():

```
oc.fetchAllShipments = function(shipment){
    shipment.fetchAllShipments().then(function(promise){
        shipment.allShipments = promise.data;
    });
};
```

The controller shall then copy the data from the shipment service to its `$scope`:

```
va.controller('OverviewCtrl',function($scope,$http,shipment){
    $scope.allShipments = shipment.allShipments;
});
```

Everything is working fine as long as i change routes from within the application, e.g I load the mainpage, then switch to /sendungen

However, if i am already on that path and decide to refresh the page, the application is loaded before the data seems to be resolved. This happens only occasionally and seems to be depending on how fast he script was executed.

How do i prevent that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function in the `resolve` should return a `promise`, not like in your `oc.fetchAllShipments` method.

> [`resolve`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. **If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved** or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the
>   values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess
>   event is fired.

For example:

```
resolve: {
  shipments: ['$q', function($q){
     var deffered = $q.defer();

     shipment.fetchAllShipments().then(function(res){
        deffered.resolve(res);
     });

     return deffered.promise;
  }]
}
```

Comment: So how do you call this?

Answer (score -3):

The quick and dirty fix will be to use $timeout:

```
va.controller('OverviewCtrl',function($scope,$http,shipment, $timeout){
    $timeout(function(){$scope.allShipments = shipment.allShipments}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Sure that'll work. But isn't resolve supposed to avoid exact that hack?
Also, i can not ensure that 1 second will be always enough to wait for the promise

Comment: didn't noticed that the promise was the problem. In that case you should return the promise from the service, then resolve it in the controller.

check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477711/force-angularjs-service-to-return-data-before-loading-controller