# What's the best Angular architecture?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have to build a component for an application in Angular and I was wondering what is the right way to do it. Basically I need the following views:

[image]

`/items` - Shows only the list of items on the left hand side

`/items/new` - Second screen would keep the list of items on the left hand side and show a container to add an item on the right hand side

`/items/1/show` - Third screen has the list of items on the left hand side and shows the item on the right hand side

My first guess is the best way to do it is create a directive for `itemsList`, another one for `new item` and another one for `show item`. Then I would create 3 routes sharing the same controller (or not) and inside the views of those 3 routes I would place the directives.

But then I realized for each time I change the URL the controller would be called again as well as each directive, so my data would be reloaded from the database. The main point of doing all this is keep the `itemsList` in the left hand side static, so if it had to reload from the database it would loose the usability I want.

*Thanks in advance for any response*

Comment: check out [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) this does exactly what you're describing, you can slice your page into different 'views` that you can update independently

Comment: @aarosil I forgot to mention that this is an application that is already built and it's not using ui-router, so I'd like to investigate possible options that don't use it

Comment: You can create a service to store `items` (to prevent reload) and inject `$location` to the directive, so you can use `$location.url()` to control what is displayed (list, detail, or add new)

Comment: @aarosil I ended up switching to ui-router, handles it in a much easier way, it turned out doing it manually was not going to be as simple

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet is to create a service that each of the views use that holds the data from the database. Then, each controller just asks the service for the data to render.

Services are singletons and are not recreated on every new page, but instead stay alive during the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Thanks mate! And the way services know whether to do an http call to retrieve data or the data is already present is as simples as doing if statements for variables storing it?

Comment: Since you're making an `$http` call, you can have the service return a promise that each controller can call `then()` on to get the data. See [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477711/force-angularjs-service-to-return-data-before-loading-controller)

Comment: I would like the itemsList to not change when the routes change, the user would have the impression that the data in the list is static as clicking in items on the list, so if I do an `$http` call the list would be refreshed and would take a while to load

Comment: If the service is an `$http` promise (because that's what it returns), it only does the http call once (when the app starts). Every time a controller uses the service, it looks at the promise, and when that promise is resolved, all other times you ask for the data it will just be there in the promise as resolved. It won't refetch the data on route change.

Answer (score 0):

An example for fetching data from a service or factory would be something like this :

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    
    angular.module('rage').factory('datacontext', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', datacontext]);

    function datacontext($http, $rootScope, $q) {        

        var service = {
            getMyData: getMyData,         //     
        };

        return service;
      
      function getMyData(domain, port, controllerpath, sessionID) {
            domain = "localhost:"
            port = "14985";            
            var url = "http://" + domain + port + controllerpath + "?sid=" + sessionID;

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.notify("Fetching list...");
            var retval = [];
            // ex. http://localhost:14985/api/controller?sid=abf843945b62cda8
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                encoding: 'JSON',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true'
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                retval = data;
                deferred.resolve(retval);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

      })();
```

and then you can have a controller associated with a view, and this controller can call into your service/factory:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage')
       .controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope','datacontext', main]);

    function main($rootScope, $scope, datacontext) {

        var settings = this;
      
      
        // Call into your datacontext factory/service
        datacontext.getDimensionsFromServer().then(function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'FAIL') {
                    if (data.messages.length > 0) {
                        console.log("Error retrieving list! ");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var dataSource = data;
                }
            });
      
    };   // end of main()    
})();
```

using the app.js file, do some initialization inside app.run()

```js
// inject 'userService' into the app.run event, and create my static list on a $rootscope variable.
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myModule', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',       
    ])
    .run(['$rootScope', 'userService',  init]);

    function init($rootScope, userService) {
        userService.getMyList().then(function (myList) {
            $rootScope.myList = myList;                
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: thanks for the well detailed example bob. I would like the itemsList to remain static as the routes change. So the user would be clicking on items on the list and only the right hand side would change. So if I retrieve the items every time with an $http call the list would be refreshing every time, right? How would you manage this?

Comment: @LucasGarcia - I understand. And no, your left static list wouldn't be loaded each time. I have some static data as well that gets loaded for a treeview widget. I added that init code in my `app.js` file. I've added the code snippet above. Using $rootScope you can save the result there; hopefully it's a small dataset so as not to clutter up the rootScope.

Comment: then in any other controller, for example, you just inject `$rootScope` and access whatever object is on there.