# AngularJS - Is there a way to inject data into a controller without using routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-controller

I have a controller in my angular application that requires some server-side initialization. I would like to do it synchronously, meaning that the data should be fetched before the controller is initiated. I synchronously load and inject data into many other controllers using the routeProvider in application configuration:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/Home', {
            templateUrl: 'default/home', controller: 'homeController',
            resolve: { 'InitPageData': ['initPageService', function (initPageService) { return initPageService.init("home/initpage"); }] }
        })
```

but I have this one controller that doesn't have a certain route or templateUrl that it's associated with. It's in a shared layout page used by many different pages and routes. I tried this, assuming that everything under the route '/' will have to pass through that, but it didn't work:

```
.when('/', {    // doesn't work
            controller: 'appController',
            resolve: { 'AppData': ['initPageService', function (initPageService) { return initPageService.init("something/initpage"); }] }
        })
```

I don't know all the routes that will end up using this controller and I don't want to care about it. Is there a way that I could specifically resolve data and inject into a controller regardless of where it's invoked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have appController be parent controller for all your other controllers.

Something similar to this:

```
<html ng-controller="appController">
```

Inside appController you could have a self executing anonymous function call which does the pre-load stuff for all your other controllers.

If you want to restrict certain child controller behavior then use a scope variable in appController to regulate them.

This is classic case of using custom events to tell other parts of application of "resolve". JS is asynchronous - you should either watch for properties, or watch of events on rootScope or use promises to handle dependent tasks.

Comment: That wouldn't work, because I'm trying to inject data into the appController, which means I want it to be resolved already before the controller is loaded.

Comment: You could create AppData as a service which gets resolved first before your AppController which depends on AppData.

Comment: It's the exact same problem in that case, I cannot make sure that the service has loaded (i.e. resolved) all the data before the controller is initiated.

Comment: This is classic case of using custom events to tell other parts of application of "resolve". JS is asynchronous - you should either watch for properties, or watch of events on rootScope or use promises to handle dependent tasks.

Comment: This is exactly what the code is doing currently, and it's working, but it would make the code simpler and slightly more efficient if I could make sure the data is there to begin with instead of first partially loading it, then watching for changes. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: There is a way to have async:false in case of jquery $.ajax but thats a very bad user experience. It literally blocks every other request from browser until the AppData request gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is only avoiding to set `resolve` repeatedly, you could write something like below.

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    function when(path, config){
        if (/* you can test path with regex or something */){
            config.resolve = { 'AppData': ['initPageService', function (initPageService) { return initPageService.init("something/initpage"); }] };
        }
        return $routeProvider.when(path, config);
    }
    when('/Home', {
        templateUrl: 'default/home', controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .when(...)
    ;
})
```

I hope it would bring some idea to you.

Comment: I tried that too, since my appController doesn't have a specific route or page, it's just shared among many pages, I couldn't inject anything into it using this approach: angular.module('myApp').controller("appController", ["$scope", "AppData", ... function ($scope, AppData ...) { // use AppData here }]);