# How to know when controller finished to load in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have a case where `app.run` sends a broadcast message to all controllers but before some of them actually loaded. And therefore they don't catch event.

Here is an example:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){    

    // I get this event too fast and GroupsCtrl still not ready
    ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
        // notify controllers on device ready    
        $rootScope.$broadcast('notifyCtrlOnDeviceReady', device);            
     });
});
```

and controller:

```
app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope){
   $scope.$on('notifyCtrlOnDeviceReady', function(event, device){
           alert('notifyCtrlOnDeviceReady - done');
       });
});
```

- I thought to create some flag in the service but it seems like a workaround.
- I also thought to create a `$watch` that listens on a service flag and sends a broadcast when all controllers finished initialization.

Is there more elegant way to notify controllers when they have loaded?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I see it you have two options here. I would not suggest using the $broadcast event system in this instance due to your issue where controllers may/ may not have been loaded.

1)
You can put a promise on the rootscope and attach then statements in your controllers:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $q){    
    var dfd = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.deviceReady = dfd.promise;

    ionic.Platform.ready(function(){  
        dfd.resolve( device );            
     });
});

app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){

   $rootScope.deviceReady.then(function( device ){
     //do something with device
   })

});
```

2) If your platform allow multiple ready functions to be registered just add it to each controller which should be run immediately if the device is ready.

```
app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){

     ionic.Platform.ready(function(){  
        //do something with device here.            
     });

});
```

Personally I would go with #2 if possible as it keeps the $rootScope cleaner, but either way should do fine. You may even try putting your ionic.Platform ready in a service and registering that, so if the API ever changes the controllers will not have to be modified later down the road.

```
app.factory("ionicPlatform"), function( $q ){
  var ready = $q.defered();

  ionic.Platform.ready(function( device ){
   ready.resolve( device );
  });

  return {
   ready: ready.promise
  }
});

app.controller('GroupsCtrl', function($scope, ionicPlatform){

     ionicPlatform.ready.then(function(device){  
        //do something with device here.            
     });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your situation is similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374636/ensuring-one-angularjs-controller-loads-before-another) (but not a duplicate) where they want to ensure a given controller is loaded first.

The answer there suggested avoiding "invisible" dependencies, and I think needing all the controllers loaded would be one.

I would suggest having a service that has both a flag and a promise function. Controllers can check the flag, and if it's not true, they call the function (maybe `WaitForLoaded()` and can have a `then` block ready to handle things. The set for the flag then `resolves` the promise, and that is only set from your `app.run` block.